# can i validate 2 conditions inside scalatest eventually block?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I tried to validate 2 conditions inside eventually block... something like this

```
eventually(timeout(Span(26, Seconds)), interval(Span(2, Seconds))) {
        response = executeSomeFunction
        response should be = (true)
        if (response) {
          something = responseResult.get
          something should be >= (10)
        }
      }
```

What am looking for is eventually should satisfy both the conditions. That is first it should check if response is true and then when response is `true`, it should validate the condition inside if loop.
I tried executing this but am getting error message

> ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" referencing to line 
>       "response should be = (true)"

Am not sure what I am trying to do is even possible inside eventually or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you write

```
response should be = (true)
```

But actually you want to write:

```
response shouldBe true
```

In your case you make assignment of `response should be: ResultOfBeWordForAny[Boolean]` to the value `true`. Not clear what conversion here you expect.

P.S. Also write `response = executeSomeFunction` outside of `eventually` block, otherwise it could be executed multiple times.

P.P.S Moreover you don't need `eventual` call if you test result of your function, it's anyway in the scope. `eventually` isn't the best practice and used when function have some async side-effects you would like to test.